# Spark - Take and Subtract

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

Is there any efficient way to take the first 1000 items from an RDD, and remove them from the RDD?

Currently what I am doing is:

```
small_array = big_sorted_rdd.take(1000)
big_sorted_rdd_without_small_array = big_sorted_rdd.subtract(
    sc.parallize(small_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a straight forward thing to do since the RDD is distributed (as the name states) so defining the 1000 first items is not straight forward.

Yet, there are ways to achieve what you are doing other than what you suggested.

First, you can define ordering on the item, for instance turn every item to tuple: (number, item), where number goes from 1 to # of elements. Then use filter on the RDD to cut the first X items:

```
big_rdd.filter(_._1 > 1000)
```

Second idea, the times I needed to get rid of X first elements was to perform an iterative calculation over the items (I remember once I tried to reduce the load on the system). So what you can do is partition your data into parts of 1000 elements in each chunk, then take a chunk at a time and perform your calculations on it, make the RDD look like this:

```
RDD[(chunkNumber, List[elements])]
```

then you will work on 1000 elements each time, taking this idea further you can make your dataset look like this:

```
Array[RDD[elements]]
```

Then work on RDD of 1000 elements each time (iterate over the array)

Answer (score 0):

val zippedRDD = rdd.zipWithIndex()

val neededRDD = rdd.filter(t => t._2 < 1000)

val unNeededRDD = rdd.filter(t => t._2 >= 1000)